# Blacklist IP database

Tags: security, proxy, wikipedia, blacklist

Is there an open database of blacklisted IP for the Web?  With a lot of public web proxy you know... such the blacklist used by the Global blocking of Wikipedia.

Comment: There are many black lists out there. Anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I would like a IP database of public web proxies (in order to block them requests).

Comment: Depending on where or how you're looking at using this, you might be better off asking on serverfault.

Comment: The Peerblock lists are good.

Answer (score 12):

The [Project Honeypot](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/?rf=41535) provides as service called [Http:BL](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl_configure.php). As an active member of Project Honeypot you can query their database of IPs that are known as email address harvesters or comment spammers.

Comment: Can I download a dump of their database?

Comment: No. You can make live DNS queries as described in http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl%5Fconfigure.php

Answer (score 8):

You can use **Blacklist IP Addresses Live Database** from myip.ms -

http://myip.ms/browse/blacklist/Blacklist_IP_Blacklist_IP_Addresses_Live_Database_Real-time

They have latest Blacklist IPs collected during the last 10 days for use in .htaccess file or in website firewall.

Answer (score 5):

[Google has a Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3#GettingStarted) that lets you check against a db of hashed values. It's public and it's encrypted. They have two databases; phishing and malware data in 2 separate blacklists. However, they contain hostnames, not IPs, but perhaps its something you could use.

Answer (score 1):

For blackips (optimized for iptables/ipset)

https://github.com/maravento/blackip

For blackdomains (optimized for squid)

https://github.com/maravento/blackweb