# If i use captcha will i be able to stop the spam completely in my blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha, spam-prevention

I have a Wordpress blog and the only user input is the commenting system. I want to totally avoid spam comments. Wordpress comes with Akismet but I can also use Captcha. Which plugin/method should I use?

My client doesn't mind users entering verification strings to post comments. If I adopt either Akisment or Captcha will I be able to completely control the spam?

Is it possible to use either Akismet or Captcha for a simple 4-digit verification? If not then please also recommend a plugin/method capable of just a 4-digit verification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The captchas [seem to be fooled](http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/) by adept people. The [Akismet](http://akismet.com/)  is better option in my view. Having said that you should still use captch along with Akismet :)

Comment: What is the sense in Akismet if to use reliable captcha? It just adds to bad usability by frequently dumping legitimate users

Answer (score 5):

No, captchas are not foolproof, so I would definitely recommend you ALWAYS use akismet when allowing comments in WordPress. Akismet will not catch everything either, so the only REAL solution is to moderate your comments. I've found Akismet + moderation to be a nice combo, however. Akismet catches almost everything, and when it doesn't, I usually only have to click the "check for spam" button again when I reach my comments page, and it's been marked as spam in the time between getting my moderation email and getting to the WP comments page.

Comment: i had been using it lately in my WP blog, it is the best antispam out there, if i use akismet then will it be wise to redirect the spam in different table in database?

Comment: WTF?! Why is my comment here -1 when it says essentially the same thing as the "winning" comment. (And was posted near simultaneously.)

Answer (score 5):

Captchas aren't perfect. I've heard of people (e.g., from India) solving captchas for cash. The best way to stop spam is a combination of:

- Captcha: proof that the user is human (although some bots can crack them). Harder captchas are harder to crack!
- Akismet: test text for spam. Also not foolproof because some messages still may come through.
- Authentication: when you authenticate users as legitimate, I think you can stop spam completely. E.g., a user becomes a trusted poster after 5 spam-free posts.

Answer (score 3):

You'll never be able to completely avoid spam, but most fully automated spambots can be stopped by something like ReCaptcha.

Comment: not true, Recaptcha actually is not so secure anymore, got cracked this year: http://www.teleread.com/2010/08/08/recaptcha-now-vulnerable-to-computer-cracking/

Comment: see my comment on youssef azari's post above.

Answer (score 3):

I saw [this video for MintEye](http://livedemo.adscaptcha.com/) the other day and thought that it was a really great alternative to captcha.

They boast a much higher solve rate and better spam protection.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to add an hidden input style text in the form, so is invisible at people, but not for bot, so when these spambot complete the form, write also in the hidden input and with a check 'if than else' you cannot receive comments or mail that are written by bot.
Exemple:

```
if($_POST['hidden_input'] != ""){
    echo('<p>You are a spambot!</p>');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best captcha solution i know so far is [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha) (same used in stackoverflow).

if you want more security, you can build your own verification system.

Comment: Re-captcha actually is not so secure anymore, got cracked this year: http://www.teleread.com/2010/08/08/recaptcha-now-vulnerable-to-computer-cracking/

Comment: ReCaptcha has been "cracked" (http://n3on.org/projects/reCAPTCHA/ -- also be sure to watch it in action: http://n3on.org/projects/reCAPTCHA/docs/recap.swf). Anyway, I definitely wouldn't trust it for anything super critical. That having been said, it's a fine solution for low traffic sites as long as you don't mind some spam getting through. Nothing is as good as moderation though.

Answer (score 0):

Never cracked and definitely the cutest captcha out there: 
http://thepcspy.com/kittenauth/

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is 100% spamproof captcha and it is wrong to count on this.
But I believe in captcha being capable to change its principles of spamstoppingn more fast and easy than spamming techniques development.

PS
The most popular captchas (reCAPTCHA, SI Captcha, etc.) do not and cannot be changed, are passable by bots .

Answer (score 0):

Using Wordfence plugin also is a good option to avoid spams.

Using Recaptcha is better than using any other captcha plugins. But Recaptcha sometimes shows nasty characters which in unreadable so sometimes your visitors will get irritated.

Many articles says that using Akismet is a good option. I think that is also a good one. But however there are some spams you cannot avoid it seems. Using the above plugins you can minimize the spams.

Answer (score 0):

Akismet is ok. Nothing else.

Akismet not stop spam. also STOP FORUM SPAM plugins too. All spammer able to post comments.

If ya have set comment moderation thats great spam block to display on ur site.

I daily get lots of spam comments. Those plugins failed to stop them.

Only little bit help.