# Choice supervised learning algorithm or unsupervised learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I would like examine a large collection of emails that are known to be spam email, to discover if there are sub-types of spam mail.

Should I using a supervised learning algorithm or an unsupervised learning algorithm ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currently best spam filter algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511412/currently-best-spam-filter-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supervised Learning. Look into Naive Bayes. It has been used to solve exactly this problem with great success in the past.